# Oboe JS only returning data when server stream dies

Tags: json, streaming, jsonstream, oboe.js

I've set up an oboe JS stream that's streaming JSON from a server. When I start listening on the stream I don't get any data, but as soon as I kill the server I get all the expected nodes. I'm guessing Oboe is caching before it returns. Here's the oboe code:

```
oboe(options /*url*/)
    .node('*', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .path('*', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .done(function(things) {
        console.log('we got it', things);
        // we got it
    }).fail(function() {  
        console.log('fail!')
    });
```

Comment: Do you get this same problem with any JSON that you're trying to load? If not, could you post the JSON that you are using?

Comment: Also, what are you using for `options`? Just the url, or any other configuration?

Comment: hard to say at the moment - I switched to basic XHR which I know oboe uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734400/fetch-vs-request

Comment: I'm leaning towards thinking the problem is in your server side code. I copied the code above into https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/vivid-swallow and see it load without a problem (at https://vivid-swallow.hyperdev.space/).

Could you remix that project and change up the server side code so that it looks more like what you're doing? Also if you can add anything that you're using in `options`, that would be helpful